# Building clojure with ant

Tags: ant, clojure

Mac OSX Lion

Used brew to install ant

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/ant.rb
```

cloned clojure git repository

```
git clone https://github.com/clojure/clojure.git
```

entered directory and ran ant

Build fails

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/pmunt/Desktop/clojure/build.xml:98: Java returned: 1
```

Relevant test failure failure

```
[java] FAIL in (Instants) (reader.clj:331)
[java] java.util.Date instants round-trips
[java] expected: (= (-> s read-string) (-> s read-string pr-str read-string))
[java]   actual: (not (= #inst "2010-11-13T06:14:15.666+10:00" #inst "2010-11-13T07:14:15.666+10:00"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing things right, but you have encountered a bug on HEAD with the new date/time literals support.

Try "ant jar" instead of "ant" to skip running the tests.

Comment: Note that this particular bug seems to be platform or time-zone specific.  That test passes for me.